# MSBuild v14 compiles a semantically incorrect assembly under some rare circumstances

Tags: c#, compilation, msbuild, binary, roslyn

After a build environment update, one of our Smoke Tests broke in TeamCity. Investigation turned out that from the same source code,

- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe produces correct binary
- C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\MSBuild.exe produces incorrect binary

**When does this occur**

- “params object[]” is used
- only a single value is passed, without being explicitly wrapped within an array
- named parameters are used
- in a different order than they were in the method signature

**Sample code to reproduce it**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var customerId = Guid.NewGuid();

    // Produces buggy code when compiled with MSBuild v14
    TestMethodWithParams(args: customerId, whatever: "foo");

    //All the calls below result correct behavior, regardless of the version of MSBuild, order and naming of parameters
    TestMethodWithParams("foo", customerId);
    TestMethodWithParams(whatever: "foo", args: customerId);

    TestMethodWithParams(args: new object[] { customerId }, whatever: "foo");
    TestMethodWithParams("foo", new object[] { customerId });
    TestMethodWithParams(whatever: "foo", args: new object[] {customerId});
}

private static void TestMethodWithParams(string whatever, params object[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("args: '{0}'", args);
}
```

**What exactly happens**

The incorrect version just **swallows the single parameter, null is being passed**. Decompiled code shows the difference:

In correct binary:

```
Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
Program.TestMethodWithParams("foo", new object[]
{
    guid
});
```

In incorrect binary:

```
Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
object obj;
Program.TestMethodWithParams("foo", new object[]
{
    obj // <- this is and will always be null
});
```

**How to fix it**

When we wrapped the single parameter into an object array, the problem was gone. Another option would be not to use named arguments, and/or make sure that the order of occurence of parameters is the same in the invocation and in the signature.

BUT: The main problem is that we cannot revert to an older MSBuild (...), and checking the whole codebase (and going through each and every binary in the crowd of our NuGet packages as well) is not an easy and effective solution. Moreover, this kind of error might be reintroduced into the codebase any time later accidentally. So the best solution would probably be to somehow fix MSBuild.

Has anyone experienced something like this? Might it be a bug in MSBuild? Ideas?

Comment: You probably want to file an issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn

Comment: Seems I can also repro this. I agree with @jessehouwing, you should file an issue on GitHub.

Comment: It's probably not too hard to write a Roslyn Analyzer that flag these calls, since the calling convention is pretty specific. That way you can easily generate a compiler error in your solutions to prevent these from sneaking through.

Comment: Created an issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/11576

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Roslyn Analyzer but that solution sounds reasonable.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/How-To-Write-a-C%23-Analyzer-and-Code-Fix

Comment: One note on the bug and the question here: MSBuild doesn't actually produce the binary, it just runs the compiler csc.exe. And the two paths you pointed to for MSBuild.exe will have different versions of csc.exe, where the actual bug (if any) lies. The question is otherwise good, you just might get some funny looks when you're discussing MSBuild versions. If you were to grab the MSBuild logs you'll see different compiler paths, and that's somewhat clearer for the bug report.

Comment: Keep your VS version updated, this bug was surely fixed in either Update 1 or Update 2 since I see no sign of it and the bug fix dates back to August 6th 2015.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I already mentioned on the GitHub issue, I believe this is the bug that was originally reported as [#4197](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4197) and was fixed in Roslyn 1.1.

Answer (score 2):

thank you for all the info and suggestions. You shared details that helped us to track down this issue. Turned out that installing "Microsoft Build Tools 2015 with Update 2" solved our problem.

Thanks again everyone.
/David